# Shouldn't Unity's dash's "find files" find files that I haven't used yet?

Tags: unity, unity-dash, search

Searching for files in Dash brings up all the files I have used but none of those I haven't used yet. Shouldn't it show all files with the title I search for instead of just the ones I have already used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Files dash of Unity shows up the most recently used files as well as the favourite folders on the home page. This behavior is by design.

If you right-click the Files dash icon in the launcher, then you can select a particular type of file (such as **Documents**, **Images**, **Presentations**, etc) and the Dash will show up all of the recently used files of that type in your home folder.

There is a found [lens](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/05/real-files-folders-search-unity-lens.html) that do deeper searches.

- Here is the [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/646724).

Comment: So there is no way to include actual searches using, for example, tracker?

Comment: Nope, that isn't supported (yet). AFAIK no one raised it in the Ayatana lists yet; you could file a bug in Unity if you would like such functionality to be available.

Comment: Looks like the relevant bug is: "[not all files show up in files-place](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/646724)"

Comment: Can't install the lens on 11.10.