# Why doesn't the search function in the Unity dash (11.04) return the same results in Nautilus search?

Tags: unity, nautilus, unity-dash, search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Shouldn't unity's dash's “find files” find files that i haven't used yet?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33551/shouldnt-unitys-dashs-find-files-find-files-that-i-havent-used-yet)

When i use the Unity dash to search for files it doesn't return the same results as when I use the nautius search.

I like the Unity dash interface and would like to use that for searching instead.

Is this right? Should it be this way? If not how do i fix it?

Comment: No. Have a look here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/33551/shouldnt-unitys-dashs-find-files-find-files-that-i-havent-used-yet