# How can I get local files to appear in unity lenses?

Tags: unity, unity-dash, lenses, zeitgeist

Perhaps I've mis-understood how the lenses are meant to work, but I find that local files or folders never show up in any of the lenses unless I've previously opened them. This is true for the file and the video lenses.

For background I've upgraded from 11.10 to 12.04 recently. My ~/Video and ~/Documents are on a seperate partition which mounts on boot.

I've tried some related fixes from jfgi

```
zeitgeist-daemon --replace
rm -rf ~/.local/share/zeitgeist
rm ~/.local/share/zeitgeist/activity.sqlite
```

but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

You can try out the [experimental file lens created by Michal Hruby](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.ubuntu.devel.desktop/3795) which uses `locate` along with zeitgeist as the result backend (also called scope)

You can add it

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-desktop/ppa

sudo apt-get update
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently unity was designed to show only recent files...

see this answer [Shouldn't Unity's dash's "find files" find files that I haven't used yet?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33551/shouldnt-unitys-dashs-find-files-find-files-that-i-havent-used-yet)

Use the Nautilus to find files, it's reliable