# Cant ubuntu dash search files from every partition of my hard drive?

Tags: files, unity-dash, directory, search

Lets say i have divided my hard disk in three partitions A B & c & i have chosen A to install Ubuntu, B to keep all my movies & all my songs in c folder. Now dash can find all my files which are there in folder (A) but is there any way it could show my movies n music files which i have kept in my B & c partition of the same hard drive.

Comment: this could be a duplicate of this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/33551/shouldnt-unitys-dashs-find-files-find-files-that-i-havent-used-yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes..Once the Drive is mounted you can acces and search those files too...
Just incase it does not for the first time,navigate to the folder once through Nautilus and then from hence fort you wont need to navigat everytime. Just mounting is enough.. :)

Comment: ohh okk it was so simple my partition was not mounted..silly me:)

Comment: ;) its alright..!! happens :p