# dash search results not showing my files

Tags: unity, files, unity-dash, search

I am using the dash search to find files(mostly video files) but its only displaying recently played files.My files are in a different partition,and yes I have mounted those drives.How do I get the dash search to index these drives and show results from them.Any help is greatly appreciated :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Unity Dash does not provide this functionality by default however you can add this with the `recoll-lens` package for Unity.

About recoll:

> Recoll is a full text search desktop tool which indexes the contents of many file formats including OpenOffice, MS Office, PostScript, MP3 and other audio files, JPEG and more.

You can install the Recoll Unity Lens with the following commands (for Ubuntu 11.04 - 13.04):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:recoll-backports/recoll-1.15-on
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install recoll recoll-lens
```

([source](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/03/recoll-lens-full-text-search-unity-lens.html))

Answer (score 0):

Apparently unity was designed to show only recent files...

see this answer [Shouldn't Unity's dash's "find files" find files that I haven't used yet?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33551/shouldnt-unitys-dashs-find-files-find-files-that-i-havent-used-yet)

Use the Nautilus to find files, it's reliable